# php output for duplicate values in foreach

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database (mysql) table like

```
id |  assign_id  |  rights    | party
---+-------------+------------+---------
1  |5            |  12        | xyz
2  |5            |  3         | xyz
3  |6            |  14        | abc
4  |6            |  5         | abc
```

Now I want to make my output in table format in this way using php foreach

```
   |  assign_id  |  rights    | party
---+-------------+------------+---------
   |5            |  12,3      | xyz

   |6            |  5,14      | abc
```

The table structure is

```
                      <th> Assign ID.     </th>
                      <th> Party Name     </th>
                      <th> rights</th>
                    </tr>

                  </thead>
                  <tbody>

                   <?php if(is_array($aryAssign)) { 
                         $cntuser=1;
                         foreach($aryAssign as $aryAssign){ ?>

                    <tr>

                      <td> <?php echo $aryAssign['assign_id']; ?>  </td>
                      <td> <?php echo $aryAssign['party']; ?>  </td>
                     <td> <?php echo $aryAssign['rights']; ?>    </td>
                                              </tr>
                    <?php   } }  ?> 

                  </tbody>
               </table>
```

Comment: query the duplicate values and then print it in the table.

Comment: what is your process till now?

Comment: You should use GROUP_CONCAT and GROUP BY in your sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT assign_id, party, GROUP_CONCAT(rights)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY assign_id, party
```